# Liferay portlet: redirect jsp to controller

Tags: redirect, liferay, portlet

I would like a jsp to automatically redirect to my controller (on load, without forms or href).

I know how to redirect a jsp to a controller via a form.
I know how to redirect a controller method to a jsp:

```
  response.setRenderParameter("mvcPath",   "page_name.jsp");
```

Would there be a similar syntax to redirect from controller to jsp?
IE something like

```
response.setRenderParameter("controllerClass",   "methodName");
```

?

If not how do you solve such issue?

thx in advance.

Answer (score 2):

It actually works the other way around - a portlet's render phase is handled in the portlet (e.g. in `doView` [see javadoc](https://docs.liferay.com/portlet-api/2.0/javadocs/javax/portlet/GenericPortlet.html#doView%28javax.portlet.RenderRequest,%20javax.portlet.RenderResponse%29)). If you're using Liferay's MVCPortlet as superclass of your own portlet, it will do the magic for you. That being said, you're free to either use JSR-286's GenericPortlet or overload `doView` yourself and implement what you'd like, so that your code runs before Liferay's implementation is delegating to a JSP.

If this makes your code easier to maintain is up to you, I doubt it.